# How are Notes Preferences Stored in MacOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, notes.app

Does the Mac Notes app store its preferences in a plist somewhere, or does it have a different method of storage? It doesn't seem to use `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.notes` as most system apps do.

I'm hoping to find a method to script its settings programmatically (i.e. `defaults write` or similar).

### Update

As [Alexander noted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287522/10167), Notes is sandboxed, and stores some data accessible via `defaults [read|write] com.apple.Notes` (case sensitive). However the preference pane settings I'm looking for (specifically the *New notes start with* setting) don't seem to be saved there. I'm hoping someone else can find where that might be kept.

Answer (score 4):

`Notes.app` is sandboxed.

Its sandbox is `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/`

Its preference list can be found at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Notes.plist`

Comment: Thanks. seems that `defaults read com.apple.Notes` (case sensitive) finds it in the sandbox just fine. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to save all its preferences there. Most of the preferences window options don't seem to have a corresponding key. I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone comes up with anything.

Answer (score -1):

I found an easy workaround. Select the yellow link text and cut. Then position your cursor next to black text, press space then select "paste and match text"
The link or links will paste in as black.

Comment: Somehow the answer doesn't seem to match the question asked. Did you post it at the intended place?