# How to have Quick Notes not "Float on top" by default

Tags: notes.app

I have macOS Monterey, and I use the "Quick Notes" hot corner. I hate the fact that every time I use the hot corner, Notes starts with the "Float on top" option, and I have to disable it manually:

[image]

Is there a way to have it off by default? I have Alfred 5.0.5 installed, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The "Float on Top" option is gone in macOS Ventura, notes will always float on top there.

Unfortunately, this means that any solution which may work in Monterey most likely will become useless once you upgrade to Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I can come up with is assigning a keyboard shortcut to "Float on Top" as per [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271). Although a built-in setting would be preferable, this method will save you time and effort.

According to [this StackExchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/287519), some of the Notes app preferences are stored in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Notes.plist` which you can tweak to your liking. If the Float on Top option is missing in your macOS version, you can try adding it, though be aware this might not work.

Comment: Please improve the answer by including all the steps in order to solve my issue, rather than linking to external sources.

Comment: @DeltaIV User pwn'cat might not be able to provide step-by-step instructions e.g. if they are already running Ventura and you still use Monterey. The instructions in https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/12.0/mac/12.0 should be easy to follow though.

Comment: @nohillside [SE answers should be self-contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18670/348050).  Or at least, that's what I've always been told on the other SE sites I wrote on (sometimes even getting downvotes for that). I didn't think of the Ventura vs Monterey issue, though.

Comment: @DeltaIV In general I agree with the self-contained aspect, we regularly point this out to users. At least on AD linking to Apple support documents usually works as well, there is not a lot of value in duplicating the information.

Comment: @nohillside ok. I tried to change my vote on the question, but I can't.